# C# WPF Label Background Color Class

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I have looked over a few different ways here on SO but have been unsuccessful when trying to change the label background color from a class to another page

I have a ServerSettings.xaml label that is called lbConnectionStatus
I also have Content\ServerSettings.xmal.cs
I have a separate class called SQLConnectionClass.cs that based on the success / fail to change the label background color of

Here is my SQLConnectionClass.cs

```
class SQLConnectionClass
{
    public void TestConnectivity(String server, String user, String pass, String db)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server +
                       ";Initial Catalog=" + db +
                       ";User ID=" + user +
                       ";Password=" + pass;
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            Connection.Close();
            success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           failed(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    void success()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success function","Message");
        Content.ServerSettings mine = new Content.ServerSettings();
        mine.lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    void failed(string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg,"Message");
        Content.ServerSettings mine = new Content.ServerSettings();
        mine.lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Red;

    }
}
```

I have tried doing the following with no luck

```
 Content.ServerSettings mine = new Content.ServerSettings();
 mine.lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Green;
```

Here is the code for Content\ServerSettings.xmal.cs

```
 namespace SQLServer.Content
 {
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for Server_Settings.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class ServerSettings : UserControl
  {
      public ServerSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLConnectionClass con = new SQLConnectionClass();
        con.TestConnectivity(tbServer.Text, tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbDatabase.Text);
    }
}
}
```

here is the code for the actual ServerSettings.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SQLServer.Content.ServerSettings"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Server Address &amp; Instance Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tbServer" Text=".\Autobase" Margin="0,10"/>
        <Label Content="Database Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tbDatabase" Text="ABSystem7" Margin="0,10"/>
        <Label Content="User-name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tbUsername" Text="sa" Margin="0,10"/>
        <Label Content="Password" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tbPassword" Text="user" Margin="0,10"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Connection Status" Margin="0,10"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbConnectionStatus" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Border Margin="0,12" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Height="15" Width="15" ClipToBounds="True"/>
            </Label>

        </Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessage" Text="TESTING THIS CRAP OUT TO MAKE SURE THAT IT WORKS THE WAY THAT IT IS SUPPOSED TO BUT I AM NOT REALLY SURE WTF I AM DOING BUT HEY I CAN AT LEAST TRY TO MAKE IT WORK CORRECTLY" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Button x:Name="btTest" Content="Test Connection" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,20" Click="btTest_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I think you should post some code about the mysterious "Content.ServerSettings" reference. The background set you used looks fine, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://psoug.org/blogs/mike/2010/04/11/little-bobby-tables/) not going to like this post ... you should use store procedures for this

Comment: I am playing with making a interface in C# why would I used a sp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a new instance of Content.ServerSettings() and then modify its label background which is a bug.

**Quick and dirty solution:**

To achieve what you need, you can pass the reference of  ServerSettings  into your SQLConnectionClass  and then change its lbConnectionStatus.Background.  *I did not test this.*

Your SQL ConnectionClass will look like

```
class SQLConnectionClass
{

    ServerSettings  _serverSettings, 

    public void TestConnectivity(String server, String user, String pass, String db, ServerSettings serverSettings )
    {

       _serverSettings = serverSettings;

        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server +
                       ";Initial Catalog=" + db +
                       ";User ID=" + user +
                       ";Password=" + pass;
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            Connection.Close();
            success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           failed(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    void success()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success function","Message");
        Content.ServerSettings mine = new Content.ServerSettings();
        _serverSettings.lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    void failed(string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg,"Message");
        Content.ServerSettings mine = new Content.ServerSettings();
        _serverSettings.lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Red;

    }
}
```

and in your ServerSettings class you can pass its reference to SQLConnectionClass

public partial class ServerSettings : UserControl
  {
      public ServerSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

```
private void btTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SQLConnectionClass con = new SQLConnectionClass();
    con.TestConnectivity(tbServer.Text, tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbDatabase.Text, this);
}
```

}

**Better way without mvvm**

Your SQLConnectionClass can return a true or false based on the success of connectivity and ServerSettings class can take care of displaying the message and modifying its label background. This way SQLConnectionClass is not tightly coupled with UI.  This is not the best approach either, but this can impose on you the idea of decoupling things.  I did not test this either.

Your SQL ConnectionClass will look like

```
class SQLConnectionClass
    {



    public bool TestConnectivity(String server, String user, String pass, String db,  )
    {

       _serverSettings = serverSettings;

        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server +
                       ";Initial Catalog=" + db +
                       ";User ID=" + user +
                       ";Password=" + pass;
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

         Connection.Open();
         Connection.Close();
         return true;
    }      

}

public partial class ServerSettings : UserControl
  {
      public ServerSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

try{
        SQLConnectionClass con = new SQLConnectionClass();
        con.TestConnectivity(tbServer.Text, tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbDatabase.Text);
         MessageBox.Show("Success function","Message");
         lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Green;

}
catch(Exception ex)       
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),"Message");
   lbConnectionStatus.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
 }
}
```